# Calculate distance to linestring

Tags: geometry, gis, leaflet, geojson

I'm noobish to GIS, so I need some help for the following.

I'd like to calculate the distance between POIs from a GeoJSON file and a linestring.
So POIs situated at a certain distance (parallel) to the linestring.

Calculating the distance between a single point ('current location') and a POI from my GeoJSON file isn't a problem (using `distanceTo()` )
But calculating the distance between POIs and a linestring goes over my head.

My ultimate goal is to use the filter option for my geoJson layer and only show POIs situated at a certain distance (parallel) to the linestring. (ex. max. distance 50 meter)

Using lat / lon in decimal degrees.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? if so I would appreciate it if you can mark it as an answer for other people who will have this problem in the future

Comment: I haven't touched to GIS software since like 2 years, but reading your problem sounds to my hears more like a mathematical (vector) issue. [This link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890582/perpendicular-line-that-crosses-specific-point) explains it better than my english words do. Is that an option to consider ? (I know geographic data can't be considered as a pure "plan", but...)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to iterate through your POIsLayer to calculate every POI with your LineLayer, and save the min distance of each point so you can get it later

```
POIsLayer.eachLayer(function(POI){
    if (POI instanceof L.LatLng) POI.mindistance = POI.distanceTo(L.GeometryUtil.closest(yourMap,    LineLayer, POI));
});
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with it. console.log(POI.mindistance) gives 'undefined' for all POIs. So where is the min distance saved and how to use it. Sorry but I'm not so experienced.

Comment: use the same lines I wrote just instead of calculating the mindistance, use it however you want

Comment: Something like:
if (POI instanceof L.LatLng) console.log(POI.mindistance);

Comment: `POIsLayer.eachLayer(function(POI){
    if (POI instanceof L.LatLng) POI.mindistance = POI.distanceTo(L.GeometryUtil.closest(yourMap, LineLayer, POI));
    console.log(POI.mindistance);
});`  prints 'undefined' while `console.log(POI)` prints all objects.  If I add ` if (POI instanceof L.LatLng) console.log(POI.mindistance);`  nothing is printed.  I've added your lines at the end of script part.  sorry for my inanity.